# FBX animations not running properly with three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx

I am having an issue with animations on some fbx models. If I have, for example an animation that lasts 20 secs, the model will stay still for 19 secs and then all changes will happen within the last second or so. On other fbx models the animation runs correctly. 
The code that I am using to run the animation is a follows:
The loader.load callback is:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var mixers = [];

function(object){
        object.position.set(0,0,0);
        object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
        mixers.push(object.mixer);
        console.log(object);
        for (var a = 0; a < object.animations.length; a++){
            var action = object.mixer.clipAction(object.animations[a]);
            action.play();
            console.log(action);
        }



        scene.add(object);
        animate();
    }
```

And the animate code is:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    for(var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++){
        mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta());
    }
    render();
    stats.update();
}

function render() {
    if (mixer) {
        mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From experience, I can tell you that the fbx ascii export process (at least for Autodesk Maya) doesn't always give either

1. the correct start and end times set in Maya or
2. gives a set of numbers that threejs doesn't import properly.

What you end up getting is -- as you describe -- a lot of time in the animation where nothing happens.  As far as I've seen, it's usually trailing at the end, but it could certainly be at the beginning as well.

You could fix the fbx file manually, but it might be easier just add a function to set the beginning time to the time of your first frame (and if the first frame is the issue, start with the second frame).

I have the code for this somewhere, let me find it and then I'll add it to this answer.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. 

When I export from Maya the animations needs to be lined up one right after the other so they don't all overlap. For example clip 1 1-10, clip 2 11-33, etc. Putting all the clips into diff tracks starting at frame 1 causes all animations to overlay onto each other, so that's not an option (unless I'm unaware of the proper export workflow).

So I guess the only options is to create a function to begin an animation at the clip's start frame. Any idea how to do this? I'm going to give it a shot myself, but wondering if you had that script handy. Thanks!

Comment: hope you found your answer already - missed your post initially.

Comment: Depending on your end goal, you could set different offsets for clips to begin playing by using the certain clips to start with a delay using animation.startAt() Or you could try starting each clip separately, triggering them off the end of the previous clip by using an event like: 
mixer.addEventListener( 'finished', function( e ) { …} );
the specifics on these can be found here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction